# How to add new dependency in Package.json file in DialogFlow?

Tags: node.js, json, dialogflow-es

I just started creating a chatbot and I want it to be multilingual. So, I am using **i18n module** for the same. I added it's dependency in the package.json but now it is showing an error:

```
The deployment of your Cloud Function failed:
Build failed: Build error details not available
```

This is my package.json file:

```
[{
  "name": "dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
  "description": "This is the default fulfillment for a Dialogflow agents using Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "license": "Apache Version 2.0",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "firebase serve --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions:dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
    "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0"
  }
},
 {
  "name": "i18n",
  "description": "lightweight translation module with dynamic json storage",
  "version": "0.8.4",
  "homepage": "http://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "http://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node.git"
  },
  "author": "Marcus Spiegel <marcus.spiegel@gmail.com>",
  "main": "./index",
  "keywords": [
    "template",
    "i18n",
    "l10n"
  ],
  "directories": {
    "lib": "."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "debug": "*",
    "make-plural": "^6.0.1",
    "math-interval-parser": "^2.0.1",
    "messageformat": "^2.3.0",
    "mustache": "*",
    "sprintf-js": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "async": "^3.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "jshint": "*",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2",
    "should": "*",
    "sinon": "*",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "zombie": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "jshint": "jshint --verbose .",
    "test": "npm run jshint && mocha --exit",
    "test-ci": "npm run jshint && istanbul cover mocha -- --exit"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}]
```

And this is my index.js file:

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const i18n= require('i18n');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

i18n.configure({
    locales : ['en-IN','hi-IN-1'],
    directory : '',
    defaultLocale : 'en-IN'
});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  function About(agent){
    agent.add(`We are a company!`);
  }

  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
  //   agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
  //   agent.add(new Card({
  //       title: `Title: this is a card title`,
  //       imageUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png',
  //       text: `This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! `,
  //       buttonText: 'This is a button',
  //       buttonUrl: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
  //     })
  //   );
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
  //   agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
  //   agent.setContext({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});
  // }

  // // Uncomment and edit to make your own Google Assistant intent handler
  // // uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);`
  // // below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched
  // function googleAssistantHandler(agent) {
  //   let conv = agent.conv(); // Get Actions on Google library conv instance
  //   conv.ask('Hello from the Actions on Google client library!') // Use Actions on Google library
  //   agent.add(conv); // Add Actions on Google library responses to your agent's response
  // }
  // // See https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-actions-library-nodejs
  // // for a complete Dialogflow fulfillment library Actions on Google client library v2 integration sample

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
   intentMap.set('About the company', About);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Most probably, the error is in the JSON file. Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the npm package: i18n to your dependencies object in package.json like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "actions-on-google": "^2.2.0",
  "firebase-admin": "^5.13.1",
  "firebase-functions": "^2.0.2",
  "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
  "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.5.0",
  "i18n" : "^0.8.4"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using multiple objects in a list inside your package.json file, I'm not sure if this is how package.json files are meant to work.

```
[{

},{

}]
```

Could you try compress all your sections down into a single object, eg.

```
{

}
```

ie, move dependencies into a single section etc.

Comment: are you talking about : `{ { },{ } }`  ?As it is also showing error. If you are talking about something else, please let me know.

Comment: You currently have [{},{}]   .  Can you please try just {} instead, I feel you are trying to declare 2 package.json contents in a single package.json